# ¿Cómo se pronuncia un número de siglo?

Tags: pronunciación, números

Cuando leo artículos de Wikipedia, o libros historicales, es muy común encontrar una frase como *siglo [numeración romana]*. Por ejemplo,

> Aljedrez, tal como se conoce actualmente, surgió en Europa durante el siglo XV.

No sé como puedo decir *siglo XV*, porque solo he encontrado en escrituras; nunca lo he oido. ¿Cuál de estas opciones es el correcto?

> siglo quince
>
> siglo decimoquinto
>
> siglo equis-ve

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cuando se trata de siglos, los números romanos del I al X se leen indistintamente como ordinales o como cardinales y se da preferencia, en el lenguaje culto, al uso del ordinal, pero del siglo XI en adelante solo se utiliza en la lectura el cardinal.

Así, por ejemplo:

- Siglo I: "siglo primero" o "siglo uno".
- Siglo II: "siglo segundo" o "siglo dos".
- Siglo III: "siglo tercero" o "siglo tres".
- Siglo IV: "siglo cuarto" o "siglo cuatro".
- Siglo V: "siglo quinto" o "siglo cinco".
- Siglo VI: "siglo sexto" o "siglo seis".
- Siglo VII: "siglo séptimo" o "siglo siete".
- Siglo VIII: "siglo octavo" o "siglo ocho".
- Siglo IX: "siglo noveno" o "siglo nueve".
- Siglo X: "siglo décimo" o "siglo diez".
- Siglo XI: "siglo once".
- Siglo XI: "siglo doce".
- Siglo XIII: "siglo trece".
- Siglo XV: "siglo quince".
- Siglo XX: "siglo veinte".
- Siglo XXI: "siglo veintiuno".

Ver el último párrafo del numeral 8 en [Cardinales - Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=cardinales&origen=RAE).

Comment: +1 por referenciar el _Diccionario panhispánico de dudas_.

Comment: No obstante, se refiere al siglo XVIX como el siglo decimonónico con gran frecuencia. Es posible oírr los otros siglos de vez en cuando (sin ser común)  con ordinales.

Comment: @guifa _decimonónico_ es un adjetivo que describe las cosas propias del s. [XIX](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bwy3wYT), pero no el siglo mismo, y podríamos decir que es de una especie distinta (acaso _sui generis_). El ordinal sería _décimo noveno_, o _décimo nono_.

Answer (score 5):

Se dice «siglo quince» siempre, como si fuera un numero arabe «siglo 15». No sigue el patrón de ingles con numeración ordinal, "fifteenth century."

Igualmente se dice «siglo veinte» y «siglo ventiuno». Nunca he escuchado los otros.

Comment: No es del todo correcto, para los siglos del I al X se utiliza la lectura como ordinales.

Answer (score -2):

Respecto de lectura ORDINAL de números Romanos, de acuerdo hasta el Decimo. A partir de ahí se dice:

1º primero / 2º segundo / 3º tercero / 4º cuarto / 5º quinto / 6º sexto
7º séptimo / 8º octavo / 9º noveno / 10º décimo / 11º undécimo / 12º duodécimo 
13º decimotercero / 14º decimocuarto / 15º decimoquinto 16º decimosexto
17º decimoséptimo / 18º decimoctavo / 19º decimonoveno / 20º vigésimo

Extraído de [Números ordinales y números romanos](http://www.cursosinea.conevyt.org.mx/cursos/comercio/libro1/parte1/unidad1/tema4/tema_1_4_31.htm):

> **Números ordinales**:
>
> Felipa fue a buscar la dirección de una oficina;
>   tenía anotado San Antonio 124, 4° piso, Col. Florida.
>
> El número del piso se lee: cuarto piso.
>
> Estos números se llaman **ordinales**, porque son los que se utilizan
>   para ordenar los elementos de una serie y, además, nos dicen qué lugar
>   ocupan dentro de la serie.
>
> A partir del número 21, se leen: vigésimo primero, vigésimo segundo,
>   vigésimo tercero, y así sucesivamente:
>
> 30º trigésimo     60º sexagésimo    90º  nonagésimo 40º cuadragésimo 
>   70º septuagésimo 100º centésimo 50º quincuagésimo 80º octogésimo

Comment: Hola Fjjorda. Este contenido está copiado de http://www.cursosinea.conevyt.org.mx/cursos/comercio/libro1/parte1/unidad1/tema4/tema_1_4_31.htm. Lee [How to reference material written by others](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) y [edit]a la respuesta para indicarlo claramente.